# Mismatch between the name of the function in the call stack and the actual location it fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am looking at a problem where a first chance memory exception is thrown. The actual location where the stack points to when it fails is not the one shown in call stack. I am unsure why there is such a mismatch and could somebody guide me on how to debug problems like these. I am using Visual Studio 2010 for debugging.

Comment: yes they all are up to date.

Comment: I can tell you from experience that under certain circumstances, exceptions don't show a proper call stack. There's (At least none that i know of) no way to change that. In this case, the only thing you can do is step-walk through your application to find out the location where the crash happens. I've had this happening quite a few times when something went wrong in DLLMain. If you use dynamic loading, double check this option.